# Nginx - how to redirect to login page after auth_request returns 401

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I do `auth_request /auth;`
as described in [configuring-subrequest-authentication/](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/configuring-subrequest-authentication/)

How can I redirect to login page if /auth returns 401 or 403?

I tried with

```
error_page 401 403 = @error401;

    location = ^/securedUrl {
        add_header dbg-header dbg_ws_3;
        auth_request /auth;
        proxy_pass http://auth-module:8080;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_pass_header x-remaining-session-time;
    }

location @error401 {
  return 302 /login-module/login;
}

location = /auth {
  internal;
  rewrite ^/(.*) /is-authorized break;
  proxy_pass http://auth-module:8080;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
}
```

but it doesn't work, I get 401 in browser

Answer (score 7):

When using proxy request,  you should set "proxy_intercept_errors on;" in the location. Like this:

```
location = ^/securedUrl {
    add_header dbg-header dbg_ws_3;
    auth_request /auth;
    proxy_pass http://auth-module:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host      $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass_header x-remaining-session-time;
    
}

location @error401 {
  return 302 /login-module/login;
}


location = /auth {
  internal;
  rewrite ^/(.*) /is-authorized break;
  proxy_pass http://auth-module:8080;
  proxy_pass_request_body off;
  proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
  proxy_set_header X-Original-URI $request_uri;
  proxy_intercept_errors on;
  error_page 401 = @error401;
}
```